# create dictionary key from 3 integer values

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, unique-key

I've got an object which has 3 integer values, combined the 3 integer are always unique. I want a quick way to find the specific object out of thousands.

my idea was to combine the 3 integers in a string so 1, 2533 and 9 would become a unique string: 1-2533-9. But is this the most efficient way? The numbers cannot be bigger than 2^16, so I could also use bit shifting and create a long which would be faster than creating a string from them I think. Are there other options? what should I do?

The main thing I want to achieve is finding the object quickly even with a collection of thousands of objects.

Comment: `long` approach seems to make sense

Comment: is the order of integers important, or 1-2533-9 means the same as 1-9-2533

Comment: Can you sort them? This way you can use Fibonacci Search in O(log n)

Comment: You could use a `Tuple<int,int,int>` and avoid generating a string. Tuple.Equals checks for value equality and Tuple.GetHashCode combines the hash codes of each item

Comment: @Nic: if he can sort them the best solution wolud be to create something like `var bigDict = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, SomeObjectClass>>>' ald index it from the smallest do the biggest. bot frankly if teh order matters this is also the way...

Comment: "But is this the most efficient way?" - is this really a requirement? There are tons of possible answers, but is performance really a concern? All are O(1) when using a proper hash function.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private readonly IDictionary<CompositeIntegralTriplet, object> _dictionary = new Dictionary<CompositeIntegralTriplet, object>();
}

public sealed class CompositeIntegralTriplet : IEquatable<CompositeIntegralTriplet>
{
    public CompositeIntegralTriplet(int first, int second, int third)
    {
        First = first;
        Second = second;
        Third = third;
    }

    public int First { get; }
    public int Second { get; }
    public int Third { get; }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        var otherAsTriplet = other as CompositeIntegralTriplet;
        return Equals(otherAsTriplet);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = First;
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ Second;
            hashCode = (hashCode*397) ^ Third;
            return hashCode;
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(CompositeIntegralTriplet other) => other != null && First == other.First && Second == other.Second && Third == other.Third;
}
```